# Не работает отправка почты через функцию mail() при отправке формы

Tags: php, html

Не срабатывает скрипт на отправку писем. Помогите разобраться, в чем может быть проблема. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит

```
<!-- Form -->
                <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

                    <fieldset>

                        <div>
                            <label for="name" accesskey="N">Как к Вам обращаться: </label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" id="name" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="email" accesskey="E">Email: <span>*</span></label>
                            <input name="email" type="email" id="email" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="comments" accesskey="M">Сообщение: <span>*</span></label>
                            <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="3" id="comments" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                    <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить сообщение" />

                </form>
```

Скрипт отправки письма

```
 <?php
// Проверка на заполненность 
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
    empty($_POST['comments'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "Заполните отмеченные поля";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['comments'];


// Создаем почту и отправляем сообщение
$to = 'msam15@mail.ru';  // Адрес получателя
$email_subject = "Посылка с контактной формы"; // Тема письма
$email_body = "Вы получили новое письмо с веб-сайта, отправленное через контактную форму.\n\n"."Детали сообщения:\n\n Имя: $name\n\n Email: $email_address\n\n Сообщение:\n $message";
$headers = "Ответить на сообщение по адресу, указанному в контактной форме: $email_address";    
$send = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 
return true;            

if ($send == 'true')
{
echo '  <div class="notification error closeable" style="display: block; float: right;">
            <p><span>Ошибка!</span> Ваше сообщение не отправлено</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
else 
{
echo '  <div class="notification success closeable" style="display: block; float: right;">
            <p><span>Спасибо!</span> Ваша сообщение успешно отправлено</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Кнопка заработала, но письмо не отправляется, не срабатывает функция mail

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых** вы плохо прочитали мануал для функции [mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php). У вас `$headers` это строка с текстом, а в функцию нужно передать строку `additional_headers`. Смотрите хотя бы пример в мануале. (см. пример в конце)

**Во-вторых** использование `return` в глобальной области видимости прекращает выполнение скрипта. [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.return.php). Так что вы никогда не увидите ваше уведомление.

**В третьих** отправка письма это большой и сложный вопрос. Если вы используете функцию [mail()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php), то нужно учитывать, что `php` не отправляет письма, а передает отправку вашему почтовому серверу. Скорее всего это [POSTFIX](http://www.postfix.org). Нужно смотреть настройки и логи.

**И в четвертых** письмо могло быть отправлено, но не доставлено. Опять же смотрите в логи и в спаме в почтовом ящике. Оно могло попасть в черные списки или спам листы. Не забудьте так же про [DKIM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) и [SPF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)

Лучше отправлять почту через SMTP сервер. Например Yandex или Google. Для `php` есть библиотека [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org)

**PS.** Вот пример рабочего кода:

```
$charset = 'utf-8'; // Кодировка письма
$to = ""; // Получатель
$subject = ""; // Тема письма
$text = ""; // Контент письма
$from = ""; // Отправитель
$fromName = ""; // Имя отправителя
// Вот что такое заголовки
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "From: =?$charset?B?".base64_encode($fromName)."?= <$from>\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=$charset\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";

return  mail("=?$charset?B?".base64_encode($to)."?= <$to>", "=?$charset?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", chunk_split(base64_encode($text)), $headers, "-f$from");
```

Comment: мануал про функцию `mail()` то может быть прочитал как раз и хорошо, видать мог позабыть.